# Expanding Menu using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to figure out a different approach of what I already have done to see other possibilities on how to code this.

If possible I would also like to add a **+** at the side when closed and a **-** when opened.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".pst_contenido > .mod100 > .pill > .caracteristicas").addClass('inactive'); 
$(".inactive").hide();

$(".boton_mas").click(function(){

  if ($(this).parent().next(".caracteristicas").hasClass('active')) {

    $(this).parent().next(".caracteristicas").removeClass('active');  
    $(this).parent().next(".caracteristicas").addClass('inactive');     
    $(this).parent().next(".caracteristicas").hide();

  }else{

    $(".pst_contenido > .mod100 > .pill > .caracteristicas").addClass('inactive');
    $(".pst_contenido > .mod100 > .pill > .caracteristicas").hide();
    $(".pst_contenido > .mod100 > .pill > .caracteristicas").removeClass('active');

    $(this).parent().next(".caracteristicas").removeClass('inactive');
    $(this).parent().next(".caracteristicas").addClass('active'); 
    $(this).parent().next(".caracteristicas").show();

  }
});  
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8z3hk6y/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something as simple as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".caracteristicas").addClass('inactive'); 
  $(".inactive").hide();

    $(".boton_mas").click(function(){
        $caracteristicas = $(this).parent().next(".caracteristicas");
        $(".caracteristicas").not($caracteristicas).addClass('inactive').removeClass('active').hide();
         $caracteristicas.toggleClass('active inactive').toggle();

    });  
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f8z3hk6y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is this

```js
   $(".itemContent > h3").click(function(){
    var hidableDiv = $(this).closest("div").find("div").first();
    

    if(!hidableDiv.hasClass("toggableTextInfo")){
       hidableDiv.toggleClass("toggableTextInfo");
       return;
    }
    else
    {
       $(".itemContent").each(function() {
          $(this).find("div").first().addClass("toggableTextInfo");
       });
       hidableDiv.toggleClass("toggableTextInfo");
    }
})
```

```css
h3{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggableTextInfo{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemContainer">
  <div class="itemContent">
      <h3>Item 1</h3>
      <div class="toggableTextInfo">
        Hello
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="itemContainer">
  <div class="itemContent">
      <h3>Item 2</h3>
      <div class="toggableTextInfo">
        Byee
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```